# Stuck in endless loop while creating buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a website, where I can insert products with a `button`.

So for now I got one `button` which creates one `div` as a product box. When the `button` is clicked it becomes invisible, under this I can see the `div` now; and under the `div`, there's the next `button` which should be able to create one more `div`s (always the same way).

The problem is that I can't find any solution to do that. I always land in an endless loop.

If you're wondering about the mailer, the idea for the first step is, to send a mail as newsletter for every created product.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

echo "<form action='index.php' method='GET'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='insert'  id='insert' value='INSERT'>";
echo "</form>";
if ($_GET["insert"]) {
    echo " <script language='JavaScript'> ";
    echo "";
    echo "  ";
    echo " document.getElementById('insert').style.visibility='hidden' ";
    echo "";
    echo "</script>";

    echo " <div class='article'>";
    echo "<h2>product</h2>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "EXAMPLE";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</div> ";
    echo "<form action='index.php' method='GET'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='ins    ert'  id='insert' value='INSERT'>";
    echo "</form>";


    //send mail
    $message = "hello TEST!";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $z; $i++) {
        mail('' . $res[$i] . '', 'Newsletter', $message);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Try to use `if(isset($_GET["insert"]))`

Comment: This could be an issue `name='ins    ert'`

Comment: hey thank u! but that doesnt rly change sth :/ dont i need a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding an "id=insert" item, and then creating a second "id=insert" item. So you get 2 identical id, which is not good.
You should "remove" the "id=insert" rather than "hide" it. jquery may help you on that.

(And so you may not need to remove the "id=insert" item, but rather "add" a new div "after" your last product).

Comment: it seems that I lost 15 reputation point by this unvalidated unswer :@

Comment: do u got them back now?